# Return an object by iterating over a 2D Array

Tags: java

In Java I have created a 2D array initialized indicating a theater with 15 rows and 10 seats per row:

`Place[][] room = new Plaats[15][10];`

Now I want to iterate over the array and giving back the object Plaats to call methods on it.

```
private Place getPlaatObject(int rownumber, int seatnumber) {
    Place places;   
    for (int row = 1; row < room.length; row++) { // loop by the rows
        for (int seat = 1; seat < room[row].length; seat++) { // loop by the seats
            return places;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I return the object?

Comment: return room[rownumber][seatnumber]; There is no need for an iteration

Comment: for (Place place : room) { *code goes here what you want to do with place Object } -> iterate through all the Place objects in the room 2d array

Comment: What do you mean by "return **the** object"?  You're iterating over the whole array and visiting **many** objects.  Which _one_ object to you wish to return?  If all you want the object at row #`rownumber` and seat #`seatnumber`,  just write `room[rownumber][seatnumber]`; no ireation needed, _and_ no `getPlaatObject` method needed.